# Apache redirect to other website

Tags: apache, redirect

First, I will explain the scenario
I have two websites built in cake3 running on two different servers. What I need is :
http://demo.com/lms  - lms is the suffix that I am using for proxy pass.

```
ProxyPass /lms/ http://lms.com/
ProxyPassReverse "/lms/" " http://lms.com/"
```

so the redirect is working fine with hot preserve.

Like when I typed http://demo.com/lms  in the URL,  the LMS site opened successfully without changing URLs.

But the problem I am facing when I clicked some link on the LMS site, it didn't work. What I see on clicking on some link like /users/login.
my URL comes  http://demo.com/users/login which is not valid.

If I append lms manually and hit http://demo.com/lms/users/login  then it is working fine.

So how can I append a prefix to each cake URL in .htaccess file so that my second site links become usable there?

123456

Comment: Maybe with the links on relative instead absolute?

Comment: Looks like the reverse did not work.  Remove the space in `ProxyPassReverse /lms/ http://lms.com/` and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Apache's mod_proxy is not designed to act as a proxy for an arbitrary website. It doesn't have any features for rewriting the HTML that passes through it to edit the URLs so they map on to the (slightly) different URL structure on your site.

You'd need to write your own code to find every HTTP Location header, HTML attribute that can contain a URL, every CSS `url()` value, every URL dynamically generated by JavaScript (the JS is where it gets *really* hard) and determine if the value was a relative path (which you would need to leave alone), absolute path (which you would need to remap), absolute URL to the same site (which you would need to remap) or absolute URL to a different site (which you wouldn't).

This is really *really* hard.